# XmlSerializer and array properties C# - Roslyn complains

Tags: c#, xmlserializer, roslyn-code-analysis

I had some classes with public array properties which were serialized and deserialized fine. Code Analyzer complained that you should not have arrays as public properties. So I changed (as suggested by CA) my properties to methods, which now set and get my private array fields.
Problem: The XmlSerializer does of course not serialize them anymore. What is the best practice to have arrays serialized without the Code Analyzer complaining?
I have also tried changing my properties into lists (second suggested solution by CA), but then CA wants them without setter which again lead to no serialization!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review and edit your question with a [Minimal Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `XmlSerializer` is old and creaky, but if it's what you have to live with, your best bet is to simply suppress the analyzer warning. Classes used for (de)serialization are typically held to the lower "whatever works" standard rather than the "whatever has a stable and unsurprising interface" standard, and the fact that an entire collection might inadvertently be replaced by clients is therefore not an issue. Consider using `DataContractSerializer`; it can serialize to private, encapsulatable fields which won't trigger such warnings.

Comment: Anytime you're asking about a problem with code, we need to see that code.  All too frequently people describe what they *think* their code is doing, not what it is *actually* doing.  So we need to see the actual code, in a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, you can overrule the CA guidance if your scenario requires it; that's absolutely fine. However! The get-only list should be fine; a typical scenario would be:

```cs
public List<Bar> Bars { get; } = new List<Bar>();
```

(optionally with some `[XmlElement]`, `[XmlArray]` or `[XmlArrayItem]` etc attributes).

If that *doesn't* work; please post a minimal example that shows it not working.

Here's an example of it working:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var foo = new Foo {
            Bars = {
                    new Bar { X = 42 },
                    new Bar { X = 12 },
                    new Bar { X = 6 },
                }
        };

        var ser = new XmlSerializer(foo.GetType());
        var sw = new StringWriter();
        ser.Serialize(sw, foo);
        var xml = sw.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(xml);
        var sr = new StringReader(xml);
        var clone = (Foo)ser.Deserialize(sr);
        foreach (var bar in clone.Bars)
            Console.WriteLine(bar.X);
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; } = new List<Bar>();
}
public class Bar
{
    public int X { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for doing the effort of making a minimal example (which would have been my task, as mentioned above). Indeed, it works - my problem was just that I forgot to initialize the List, so afterwards it was always null. In future questions, I promise to include minimal examples, so that the error can be easily seen.